# remote access sqlite or mysql database

Tags: java, mysql, sqlite, jsp, t-sql

I am using sqlite for my offline J2EE applicaion . But I have two client and I want to connect database of two clients together .

Can I do it with sqlite or I have to change mysql ? And can you show me which host can help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access SQLite remotely just using its native capabilities without some kind of an extra bridge, e.g ssh tunnel or a custom proxy daemon. MySQL and a number of other databases do provide remote access. There are a lot of hosting providers that manage MySQL for you, e.g Rackspace, Amazon, Bluehost, and many others, or if you just get a host with Linux and root access you can install it yourself, and there are many providers that can give you that - I personally like Linode.

Comment: So if it's microsoft sql server. Which host can I use. Thank you very much.